# Extract element from JSON file in S3 bucket using boto3

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have created an AWS Python Lambda which simulates data and sends it as messages to a relevant AWS IoT topic.

Instead of reading the Client_ID from the os.environ in the lambda I am wanting to pull them from the JSON file that I have stored in S3  using boto3

Comment: You would need to call `download_file()`, then process the file locally.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using "S3 Select" which allows you to query a file in S3 directly without having to download the file to the system.  In boto3 it's called [select_object_content](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.select_object_content).  I built out a sample below from your info and the boto3 page.

```
response = client.select_object_content(
    Bucket='mybucketname',
    Key='simulated/config/IoT-sim-config.json',
    Expression="SELECT s.* FROM S3Object s WHERE s.client_id = 'Sim_1'", # You will need to fiddle with the quotes on the SQL here.
    ExpressionType='SQL',
    InputSerialization={
        'JSON': {
            'Type': 'DOCUMENT'
        }
    },
    OutputSerialization={
        'JSON': {
            'RecordDelimiter': ','
        }
    }
)
```